# Android checkbox size (of drawable)

Tags: android, checkbox, size, customization

Im trying to customize a check box

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Produsele si factura trebuie sa ajunga la aceeasi adresa"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

The selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" android:state_checked="true" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_white"></item>

</selector>
```

@drawable/checkbox is a photo while checkbox_white is a shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <size
        android:height="15dp"
        android:width="15dp" />

</shape>
```

As you can see when the button is unchecked the image is a white 15X15 shape but when I click it I want it to **change to the image in drawable and also set it to 15x15dp**. I tried to add the drawable in a shape but the app crashes.

Comment: why don't you edit the image from drawable to make it 15x15 dp, and after paste it to drawable?

Comment: i think he did that... i don't know why the app crashes, a logCat output would help...

Comment: it crashes when I tried to do this:

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@drawable/checkbox" />

    <size
        android:height="15dp"
        android:width="15dp" />

</shape>

I need the size to be in dp not px.